# Using common lisp to re-roll selected dice, and keep unselected using user input

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have these two basic functions:

```
(defun dice ()
  (+ 1 (random 6)))

(defun five-dice ()
   (list (dice) (dice) (dice) (dice) (dice)))
```

All they do is create a list of five rolled dice. What I want to do is pick a certain number of dice to roll again. Meaning, I want to pick either 2, 3, or all five to roll again, and replace the dice that are re-rolled while keeping the ones I decide not to roll. I want to do this using user input.

My assumption is that the best way to do this is to use a symbol, but I've been trying for about a day and cannot figure how how exactly to do this. That is why I decided to seek help.

**Edit:** Thank you guys for all your help, I really appreciate it. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how lisp accepts user input, and how to store that into variable.

So, I create a global variable, and use that as the user's initial roll, but once I try use the input from the user to re-roll certain dice, that's the part I'm having trouble comprehending. I've looked at a few examples, and I've tried to recreate it, but it doesn't workout for me:

`(defun testfunction()
               (terpri)
               (princ "would you like to roll? ")
               (read-line)
           (if (member (read-line) '("y" "yes" "") :test #'string=)
         (let ((roll (five-dice)))
           )))`

This is what I'm trying to get to work, so, after the user enters yes or y, it'll give them their 5 dice, and it'll give them 3 chances to re-roll any number of dice they want. So, this is what I'm currently trying to get to work.

**Edit2:**

`(defun roll-again(lst)
 (if (null lst)nil
 (setf (nth (car lst) list-dices)(dice))
  (yup (cdr lst))
   ))`

Why isn't this function working? What I'm trying to do now is use this function to re-roll the dice the user picks. So, once I get input from the user, I put that input into a list, then use this function to re-roll those dice. But, I cannot get this function to work for some reason.

Comment: *The best way to do this is to use a symbol*. What do you mean? Could you show an example interaction with the user which would show the different use cases?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [`MAPCAR`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) to go through the list, asking the user if they want to re-roll the dice.

```
(defun dice ()
  (1+ (random 6)))

(defun roll-dice (&optional (n 5))
  (let ((dice (loop repeat n collecting (dice))))
    (format *query-io* "Rolled: ~{~a~^, ~}." dice)
    (finish-output *query-io*)
    (mapcar (lambda (d)
              (if (y-or-n-p "Roll ~a again?" d)
                  (dice)
                  d))
            dice)))
```

**Edit**

In your edit you said the user should be able to re-roll any number of dice up to three times. Here's a version that lets them do that:

```
(defun roll-dice (&optional (n 5))
  (loop with dice = (loop repeat n collecting (dice))
        for rolls-left from 3 downto 1
        while (y-or-n-p "Rolled: ~{~a~^, ~}.~@
                         Re-roll (~a re-roll~:*~p left)?"
                        dice rolls-left)
        do (map-into dice
                     (lambda (d)
                       (if (y-or-n-p "Roll ~a again?" d)
                           (dice)
                           d))
                     dice)
        finally (return dice)))
```

Comment: You might need to call `finish-output` (I recently received the same comment, it's my turn now).

Comment: @coredump I added it to be safe, but it might be redundant since I'm pretty sure `Y-OR-N-P` must call it in any case.

Comment: You are probably right: looking at SBCL's [source code](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/src/code/query.lisp#L35), it actually forces output after asking the question, so it works as expected. I was wondering about that too but couldn't find a definitive reference about whether we can safely expect it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for small list your best otion is to acces to elements to the list and modify it. use for example the function nth, if you want to modify the second element you can do like this:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter list-dices (five-dice))
LIST-DICES
CL-USER> list-dices
(1 5 2 3 2)
CL-USER> (setf (nth 1 list-dices) (dice))
2
CL-USER> list-dices
(1 2 2 3 2)
```

Comment: So, how would I use that with user input, and multiple dice? 
So would I do this: 


(format t ....................)


((setf (nth read-line list-dices) (dice))

Just replacing the integer with read-line, because that's what I was trying to do and it wasn't working.

edit: How would that work if the user wants to reroll 2 dice, or more.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for the re-rolling:

```
(defun reroll-specific-dice (dice-list reroll-list)
  "Takes a list of dice results, and a list of dice indexes to reroll,
   returns a list of those dice, re-rolled. This function is non-destructive."
  (let ((dice-list (copy-list dice-list)))
    (loop for reroll-index in reroll-list
       do (setf (nth reroll-index dice-list) (dice)))
    dice-list))
```

This can be made destructive by skipping the `let`/`copy-list`, but non-destructive is in general better. This also does no error checking. It also doesn't deal with getting input from the user, because doing that in a really user-friendly manner is something I don't have ttime to write.

For a "minimal" user input, you could do something like:

```
(defun get-dice-to-reroll ()
  (format t "Provide a list of dice to reroll, between parentheses: ")
  (finish-output)
  (read))
```

Again, this has minimal error checking, but returns a list that is suitable to feed in as the `reroll-list` to `reroll-specific-dice`.